# SharePoint apps using Angular JS

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'am new to SharePoint Apps and i want to develop some sample SharePoint Apps using Angular JS, web api and MVC 5.

Please suggest me a Good Tutorial for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of apps you want to develop? SharePoint Hosted or Provider Hosted app?

I have an article for SharePoint Hosted App using AngularJs.

[SharePoint 2013 and Angularjs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002526/SharePoint-and-Angularjs)

In Provider Hosted App, you will be not be able to execute direct `$http` requests like following

```
$http({
        url: baseUrl + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    })
    .success(function(result) {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    })
    .error(function(result, status) {
        deferred.reject(status);
    });
```

In that case, you have to use [SP.RequestExecutor.executeAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735920.aspx)

Comment: i need SharePoint Hosted. But, your article is not loading.

Comment: Meaning you can not access it? If so then try from different ISP

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best course about SharePoint apps and AngularJs is Andrew Connell course at PluralSight

https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/building-sharepoint-apps-spa-angularjs/table-of-contents

And you can get free PluralSight subscription for 6 month, just register at
https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-dev-essentials-vs
Also you get there additional benefits.